# Limitar decimales sin redondear

Tags: java

Tengo este numero: 7253.9289
y quiero imprimir el número dependiendo los decimales por ejemplo:

- 7253.9
- 7253.92
- 7253.928
- 7253.9289

He probado con `round` y `decimal format` pero me los redondea y es lo que no quiero, existe alguna manera?

Comment: te sugiero revisar lo siguiente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8487819/5215609

Comment: Transfórmalo en string y tomas el substring

Comment: Por cierto, cómo probaste con decimalFormat y round? Añade el código relevante a tu pregunta, por favor

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un modificador de `java.text.DecimalFormat`

```
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

//...
        Double d = 8.123456;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        String s = df.format(d);
        d = df.parse(s).doubleValue();
        System.out.println(d); // imprime 8.1234
//...
```

Documentación:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setRoundingMode-java.math.RoundingMode-

Comment: El OP no quiere redondeo, sólo truncar el número.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione con este metodo: x = numero de decimales, y y = numero de decimales -1

```
static void  imprimirdecimales1x1(double doubleValue) {
    String value = String.valueOf(doubleValue);
    if (value != null) {
        result = value;
        int decimalIndex = result.indexOf(".");
        if (decimalIndex != -1) {
            String decimalString = result.substring(decimalIndex + 1);
            if (decimalString.length() > x) { //n +1
                result = value.substring(0, decimalIndex + y); // n + 1
            } else if (decimalString.length() == 1) {
                result = String.valueOf(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basado en la respuesta de a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486878/how-to-cut-off-decimal-in-java-without-rounding/8487819#8487819) :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double d = 7253.9289;

    print(d, 1e1);
    print(d, 1e2);
    print(d, 1e3);
    print(d, 1e4);

}

private static void print(Double d, double exponent) {
    double dd = Math.floor(d * exponent) / exponent;
    System.out.println(dd);
}
```